# libsqlite and dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

If libsqlite is not thread safe a code like that

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

__block NSArray *__albumsCollection = albumCollections;

dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) 
{ 
   MPMediaItem *albumObj = [[__albumsCollection objectAtIndex:i] representativeItem];

   ///// making some sqlite queries    
});
```

would raise a BAD_EXEC.

So how to make this code thread safe?

My solution was using the main queue

```
dispatch_apply(count, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(size_t i) 
{
   /// my sqllite queries
});
```

but I'm not satisfied with that. How to make it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to get the main queue you might want to create a separate [**private dispatch queue**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) on a non-main thread like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); // or NULL as last parameter if prior to OS X 10.7/iOS 5.0
dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
 /// your SQLite queries
});
```

---

Alternatively you could use a `FMDatabaseQueue` from Gus Mueller's ([@ccgus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23326/ccgus)) brilliant [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) SQLite wrapper framework (which is what I'd do):

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:aPath];

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

    // Your SQLite queries:
    [db executeQuery:@"...", ...];
    ...

}];
```

…which will send your query block to a serial dispatch queue, wrapping its execution synchronously.

Not convinced yet?

```
[queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {
    // Your SQLite queries:
    [db executeQuery:@"...", ...];
    ...
}];
```

How about now?

Also, [custom-defined block-based SQLite functions](https://gist.github.com/ccgus/3238464).

Comment: Yes, except he probably wants a serial dispatch queue so that only one thing runs at a time. (Since sqlite can't be accessed from multiple threads at once.) So, he needs to pass DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL in the second argument of dispatch_queue_create.

Comment: @JesseRusak: ["Dispatch queues created with the DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL or a NULL attribute invoke blocks serially in FIFO order."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right; I thought the other way was the default because all the global queues are concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t q=dispatch_queue_create("name", NULL);
dispatch_sync(q, ^{
//your code is here
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
//as soon as above block is completed, this block executed and you will be notified that     
//work is completed

});
```